# How to check if a user is disabled or not in Firebase when authenticating?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Interesting enough I could not find a single place where it clarifies how to check if a user is disabled to prevent him from logging in.

As you can see in the documentation the [User object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#properties) does not contain any property called `disabled` so how am I suppose to validate if a user who is trying to log in is disabled or not?

my code to sign in:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(login_email, login_password)
        .then((onfulfilled, onrejected) => {
            console.log(onfulfilled); //no disabled property is printed
             })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are missing a catch block. Firebase should return an error when trying to sign in (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) in the firebase docs).

```
auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(login_email, login_password)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('User account created & signed in!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.code === 'auth/user-disabled') {
      console.log('Sign-in for this email address is disabled!');
    }
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the doc, is the user is disabled, the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) method will fail with an error which has an `auth/user-disabled` code. You will be able to detect this case through a `catch()` as follows:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(login_email, login_password)
        .then(userCredential => {
            console.log(onfulfilled); //no disabled property is printed
        })
        .catch(error => {
           if (error.code === 'auth/user-disabled') {
             // User is disabled
           }
         })
```